# Redirect to file mysteriously does nothing in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

#### Background

I've a script. It's purpose is to generate config files for various system services from templates whenever my gateway acquires a new IP from my ISP. This process includes making successive edits with `sed` to replace `$[template]` strings in my custom templates with the correct information.

And to do *that* I've created a small function designed to take input from stdin, redirect it to a temporary file passed as an argument, and then move that file to replace the destination (and also, often, source) config file. The "edit-in-place dance", if you will.

I created a simple test script with the problematic function:

```
#!/bin/bash

inplace_dance() {
   read -r -d '' data
   printf '%s' "${data}" > "${1}~"
   mv "${1}~" "${1}"
}

# ATTN: ls is only being used to generate input for testing. It is not being parsed.
ls -l ~/ | inplace_dance ~/test.out
```

Unfortunately, this works. So it's not the function itself. I also tried it with my custom logging utility (see "complications" below):

```
#!/bin/bash

. /usr/local/lib/logging.bash
log_identifier='test'
log_console='on'

inplace_dance() {
   read -r -d '' data
   printf '%s' "${data}" > "${1}~"
   mv "${1}~" "${1}"
}

# ATTN: ls is only being used to generate input for testing. It is not being parsed.
bashlog 'notice' $(ls -l ~/ | inplace_dance '/home/wolferz/test.out')
```

This also works.

#### The Problem

In its original context, however, it does *not* work. I've confirmed that `${data}` gets set just fine. And that `${1}` contains the correct filename. What fails is the second line of the function. I've confirmed `printf` is being run (see, "Additional Info - Without The Redirect" below)... but **the file its output is being redirected to is never created.**

And I've been over the code a dozen-dozen times (not an exaggeration) and have yet to identify the cause. So, in desperation, I'm going to post it here and hope some kind soul will wade through my code and maybe spot the problem that I'm missing. I'd also happily take advice on improvements/replacements to my logging utility (in the hopes of tracking down the problem) or further troubleshooting steps.

Here is the [original context](https://gist.github.com/JadedDragoon/3a0805903478309e12dfc87dab01a985). The important lines are [106-110](https://gist.github.com/JadedDragoon/3a0805903478309e12dfc87dab01a985#file-dhcpcd-exit-hook-L106), [136-140](https://gist.github.com/JadedDragoon/3a0805903478309e12dfc87dab01a985#file-dhcpcd-exit-hook-L136), [144-147](https://gist.github.com/JadedDragoon/3a0805903478309e12dfc87dab01a985#file-dhcpcd-exit-hook-L144), and [151-155](https://gist.github.com/JadedDragoon/3a0805903478309e12dfc87dab01a985#file-dhcpcd-exit-hook-L151)

#### Additional Info

☛ PATH/Environment

The `PATH` is `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`. I believe this is being inherited from systemd (`systemd`=>`dhcpcd.service`=>`dhcpcd`=>`dhcpcd-run-hooks`=>`dhcpcd.exit-hook`).

`dhcpcd-run-hooks` (see "Complications" below) does clear the environment (keeping the above PATH) when it runs. Thus, I've added an example of the environment the script runs in to the "original context" gist. In this case, the environment when `$reason == 'BOUND'`. This is output by `printenv | sort` [at the end of execution](https://gist.github.com/JadedDragoon/3a0805903478309e12dfc87dab01a985#file-dhcpcd-exit-hook-L178) (and thus should show the final state of the environment).

*NOTE:* Be aware this is Arch Linux and the absence of `/bin`, `/sbin`, and `/usr/sbin` in the `PATH` is normal (they are just symlinks to `/usr/bin` anyway).

☛ Return Code

Inserting `echo $?` after the second line of the function gives me a return code of "0". This is true both with the redirect in line 2 and without (just the `printf`).

☛ Without The Redirect

Without the redirect, in the original context, the second line of the function prints the contents of `${data}` to stdout (which is then captured by `bashlog()`) exactly as expected.

⚠️ Execute Instead of Source.

Turns out that `$0` was `/usr/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks` rather than my script. Apparently `dhcpcd-run-hooks` doesn't execute the script... it sources it. I made some changes to line [196](https://gist.github.com/JadedDragoon/3a0805903478309e12dfc87dab01a985#file-dhcpcd-exit-hook-L196) to fix this.

**♔ Aaaaaand that seems to have fixed all problems. ♔**

I'm trying to confirm that was the silver bullet now... I didn't notice it was working till I had made several other changes as well. If I can confirm it I'll submit an answer.

#### Complications

What complicates matters quite a bit is that it's original context is a `/etc/dhcpcd.exit-hook` script. [`dhcpcd-run-hooks`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/dhcpcd-run-hooks.8.html) appears to eat all stderr and stdout which makes troubleshooting... unpleasant. I've implemented my own logging utility to capture the output of commands in the script and pass it to journald but it's not helping in this case. Either no error is being generated or, somehow, the error is not getting captured by my logging utility. The script is running as root and there is no mandatory access control installed so it shouldn't be a permissions issue.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for starters

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would read the actual question before commenting. In the examples `ls` is only used to produce output to test with. It's not being parsed. And in the actual usage `ls` is never run.

Comment: Are relative paths being used, and is the current working directory what you think it is? Are you looking in the right place for the output?

Comment: How about running the whole thing under `strace -f -o /path/to/strace.log ...` to capture all the system calls, like what files are being opened and written.

Comment: What happens if you remove the redirect to file (not a pipe, actually ;)). Do you get the expected output, IOW is printf executed properly?

Comment: More ideas: a) output the exit code `echo $?` after the call to `printf`. b) run the script with `bash -x` (prints all executed commands after expansion but before executing them)

Comment: @Kaz In the original context, no... absolute paths. I'll try `strace`. @knittl In the original context I have no way to find out as stdout gets eaten by the parrent process... or, maybe... i'll try something and come back to that. Also I'll try the other ideas... but I'll have to make sure stdout is getting captured by my logging util to see the output. Let me try.

Comment: One more idea: it could be that your parent process (`dhcpcd-run-hooks`) resets the environment, before running any script. So your script will not have any `$PATH` or other variables set. If you depend on a binary being available in `$PATH` (using simply the binary name and not the absolute path), this colud well fail.

Comment: Also, what happens when your run your script manually instead of having it executed by `dhcpcd-run-hooks`? Same behavior? Different behavior? Unable to run?

Comment: @knittl A good point. Yes, it absolutely does reset the environment (says so in it's manpage). `read`, `printf`,  and `echo` are builtins... but `mv` is not. I'll switch that to use an absolute path just in case. Should probably do the same for sed and anything else that's not a builtin. They are working, but better not to trust it. Running the script without runhooks results in the environment missing required variables that are normally set by the parent, i'd have to simulate those variables to test it that way. But it's doable.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong If `mv` is not found, though, you should be able to find the unrenamed `~` file.

Comment: Updated question with additional info. I seem to have stumbled upon a solution. Trying to confirm the exact solution now.

Comment: you can remove \ after `|` or `$(`. Instead of |\ or $(\ just `|` or `$(`. You also don't need the \ on command end, like [here](https://gist.github.com/JadedDragoon/3a0805903478309e12dfc87dab01a985#file-dhcpcd-exit-hook-L127) just remove it. You can save some cpu cycles, by doing `<<<"${prefixes[0]}"` instead of `printf '%s' "${prefixes[0]}" | `.

Comment: Another helpful place to start, in terms of getting enough details to let folks help you, is to have such a script start (after the shebang, of course) with something like `exec 2>/tmp/my-log.$$; PS4=':$LINENO+'; set -xv`, putting a log of commands run and errors from same in a fixed location; if there's a "command not found" running `mv`, it'll be in that log.

Comment: BTW, do you think you can distill this down to a specific, narrow question about bash-the-language, with unrelated content elided? If so, the answer should be taken out of the question and added with the "Add an Answer" button (you're welcome to answer your own question, and will be able to accept that self-answer after a delay). However, if there's so much involved that someone needs to have a great deal of identical context and circumstances to benefit from the question/answer pair, it's probably better deleted.

Comment: Actually I just asked about that [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389134/not-sure-if-i-should-add-detail-to-question-or-submit-answer-and-start-new-quest). I'm not sure why what I did works, and am unsure if I can give a good answer as a result.

Comment: I do believe this problem could be more general than this case... but I need to understand the problem and solution to know that for sure.

Comment: @Charles Duffy No response to the meta question. I've done more digging and I'm now convinced it's some odd interaction with `task-spooler` and how I was unknowingly calling `dhcpcd-run-hooks` a second time from within the same environment. All `dhcpcd-run-hooks` is doing is sourcing my script which, in and of itself, should not cause this malfunction. In otherwords I'm still not clear on why this is happening... but I am clear that this is _not_ a generalized problem but rather something very specific to my case. Migrate or delete as needed.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong if the script is sourced, it is not necessarily executed with the interpreter specified in your shebang line. Simplified, the complete script is simply coied to the other script and the shebang line turns into a regular comment. So if your script contains bashism and is executed with `sh`, it might not work either.

Comment: Yes, in fact the sourcing script has a shebang for bourne shell. Fortunately, on my system (Arch), `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`. Though I suppose it's possible that bash detects this and behaves differently when executed this way.